# adverb phrase or adjective phrase

Tags: adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

> You can take a short ferry ride from the city of Surabaya to Madura for a heart-stopping bull race, **filled with excitement**.

In the sentence, is the phrase "filled with excitement" adverb phrase or adjective phrase? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an adjective phrase.

Comment: It's an adjective phrase reduced from the adjective clause " which is filled with excitement" , modifying the phrase " a heart-stopping bull race."

Answer (score 3):

"Filled with excitement" is an adjective phrase, in which "filled" is an adjective and "with excitement" is its complement.

Answer (score 2):

It's a non-restrictive adjective phrase, headed by the participial adjective **filled**. The adjective itself is modified by the prepositional phrase **with excitement**, which serves as its complement.

This adjective phrase most likely modifies **a heart-stopping bull race**. It theoretically can modify **a short ferry ride**, but it's too far from it.

An adverbial phrase modifies a verb, an adjective, or an adverb.

Had it been an adverbial phrase, it would've modified **take a ride**, but this would've looked strange:

> You can take a ride, **filled with excitement**. (seems to modify either **you** or **ride**)
>   You can take a ride **excitedly**. (now it surely modifies [take a ride])

We can use **filled with excitement** predicatively:

> This ride *is/seems/feels* **filled with excitement**.

Answer (score 0):

**excitement** is a noun and **filled** a verb in past simple form, but this is not the case.

*filled* works as an adjective, like *full* or *complete* so *filled* with *excitement* (noun) works as an adjective phrase.

Comment: I don't agree; I think the phrase "filled with excitement" must be an adjective phrase or an adverb phrase.
 But thank you.

Comment: @TheinLwin It's been edited, check it now.